# JPanel in JTable gets focus on mouse click but not on mouse over

Tags: java, swing, jtable, mouselistener

I have a table with one column containing JPanels. I have written the custom renderer and editor and they work fine. However, the panel contains a JLabel component with a tool tip. If I click into the cell and hover over the label the tool tip is displayed, but if I move the mouse into the cell and hover over the JLabel the tool tip wont display. I have added a mouse listener to the table as shown below where I get the Panel object and try to make it have focus.

```
public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
    Point p = e.getPoint();
    int row = table.rowAtPoint(p);
    int column = table.columnAtPoint(p);
    System.out.println(row + " " + column);
    Object o = table.getModel().getValueAt(row, column);
    if (o instanceof FileInfoCellPanel) {
        FileInfoCellPanel ficp = (FileInfoCellPanel)o;
        ficp.requestFocusInWindow();
        //ficp.revalidate();
    }
}
```

I am definitely getting the correct JPanel object but it never seems to get focus. So clicking in the cell seems to give focus to the panel but moving the mouse does not.

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to display text in your tooltip, it is sufficient to set the tooltip on the component which you return by the renderer. This can be seen if you look at the implementation of the `JTable#getTooltipText` method, which I copied below

```
public String getToolTipText(MouseEvent event) {
    String tip = null;
    Point p = event.getPoint();

    // Locate the renderer under the event location
    int hitColumnIndex = columnAtPoint(p);
    int hitRowIndex = rowAtPoint(p);

    if ((hitColumnIndex != -1) && (hitRowIndex != -1)) {
        TableCellRenderer renderer = getCellRenderer(hitRowIndex, hitColumnIndex);
        Component component = prepareRenderer(renderer, hitRowIndex, hitColumnIndex);

        // Now have to see if the component is a JComponent before
        // getting the tip
        if (component instanceof JComponent) {
            // Convert the event to the renderer's coordinate system
            Rectangle cellRect = getCellRect(hitRowIndex, hitColumnIndex, false);
            p.translate(-cellRect.x, -cellRect.y);
            MouseEvent newEvent = new MouseEvent(component, event.getID(),
                                      event.getWhen(), event.getModifiers(),
                                      p.x, p.y,
                                      event.getXOnScreen(),
                                      event.getYOnScreen(),
                                      event.getClickCount(),
                                      event.isPopupTrigger(),
                                      MouseEvent.NOBUTTON);

            tip = ((JComponent)component).getToolTipText(newEvent);
        }
    }

    // No tip from the renderer get our own tip
    if (tip == null)
        tip = getToolTipText();

    return tip;
}
```

As can be seen, to determine the tooltip text the renderer is asked for a component, and that component is asked for its tooltip text. Of course this only works for texts and not for e.g. images